# iconv supports too few encoding

Tags: ubuntu, centos, encoding

`iconv -l` outputs too few encodings on CentOS 6.5:

```
 $ iconv -l
  10646-1:1993, 10646-1:1993/UCS4, ANSI_X3.4-1968, ANSI_X3.4-1986, ANSI_X3.4,   ASCII, CP367, CSASCII, CSUCS4, IBM367,
  ISO-10646, ISO-10646/UCS2,   ISO-10646/UCS4, ISO-10646/UTF-8,
  ISO-10646/UTF8, ISO-IR-6, ISO-IR-193,   ISO646-US, ISO_646.IRV:1991,
  OSF00010020, OSF00010100, OSF00010101,   OSF00010102, OSF00010104,
  OSF00010105, OSF00010106, OSF05010001, UCS-2,   UCS-2BE, UCS-2LE,
  UCS-4, UCS-4BE, UCS-4LE, UCS2, UCS4, UNICODEBIG,   UNICODELITTLE,
  US-ASCII, US, UTF-8, UTF8, WCHAR_T
```

But on my Ubuntu the list seems much longer, here is different:

**CentOS6.5:**

```
$ php -a 
php > echo iconv('utf8', 'gbk', 'abc');
PHP Notice:  iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from `utf8' to `gbk' is not allowed in php shell code on line 1 
php > quit 
$ php -i|grep iconv

iconv
iconv support => enabled
iconv implementation => glibc
iconv library version => 2.12
iconv.input_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
```

**Ubuntu 14.04:**

```
$ php -a Interactive mode enabled

php > echo iconv('utf8', 'gbk', "abc\n");
abc 
php > quit 
$ php -i|grep iconv

iconv
iconv support => enabled
iconv implementation => glibc
iconv library version => 2.19
iconv.input_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
```

But I don't want to recompile glibc(this will be huge mount of work), any idea on how to ad new encoding support?

Comment: What version of glibc do you have? iconv -l spits out a huge list for me on CentOS 6.5 and the PHP function works fine too.

Comment: I solve this by run `yum upgrade'.

Answer (score 0):

After `yum upgrade`, iconv works well when glibc-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64 is installed, while the old package is 
 glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64.